# JQuery DataTables warning (table id = 'someId'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When my dataTable is empty worning appears: "DataTables warning (table id = 'someId): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0". When there is some data everething is ok. I use JSF 2.1 component  for creating my dataTable; This is my JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.examDataTable').dataTable({
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "bFilter" : false,
            "bSort" : false,
            "bInfo" : false,
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "aLengthMenu": [1, 3, 5],
            "iDisplayLength" : 3,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "#{msg['JQUERY_DTABLE_sLengthMenu']}",
                "sZeroRecords": "#{msg['JQUERY_DTABLE_sZeroRecords']}",
                "sProcessing": "#{msg['JQUERY_DTABLE_sProcessing']}",
                "sEmptyTable": '',
                "sInfoEmpty": '',
                "oPaginate" : {
                    "sPrevious" : "#{msg['JQUERY_DTABLE_sPrevious']}",
                    "sNext" : "#{msg['JQUERY_DTABLE_sNext']}"
                },
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's your generated table look like when there is no data? I suspect you have an empty row like <tr></tr> or similar.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I have an empty rows <tr></tr>.

Comment: Remove it.  That is the problem.

Comment: did you find solution? I have same problem...

Comment: Yes. I had to debug and modify JQuery DataTable plugin for my purposes. I know, it is just work around, but I didn't find another way.